# How can I install dpkg and aptitude on Raspbian?

Tags: apt, raspbian, dpkg, yocto

I've downloaded and burn a yocto raspbian image, I found out I've no apt nor dpkg but only pkg-config and wget, how can I install them?
Or at least how could I install dpkg in order to install apt in the aftermath using wget and dpkg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raspbian includes `dpkg` and `apt`; what you’ve downloaded presumably *isn’t* Raspbian, but a Raspberry Pi Yocto image. The latter kind of image isn’t designed to be modified, and you shouldn’t try to add `dpkg` to your image.

Put another way, if you want Raspbian, make sure you download a Raspbian image.

Comment: Ok, so there is no way to install dpkg without apt?There is not dpkg's source code for the raspberry pi to be compiled and installed?

Comment: You can build `dpkg` from source, yes, but there would be no point in doing so, because you wouldn’t be able to use it to manage packages on your Yocto system (because there aren’t any, in the generated image).

Comment: Put another way, `dpkg` and `apt` aren’t magical tools you can install anywhere to suddenly be able to manage packages with them; they only work with `dpkg`-based distributions.